# Simple Php Mailer.php and a contact.html, need html help might be missing few tags

Tags: php, html

Hi im totally new to php, i have a website where i have a contact.html,it has forms where in name, email, insurance type, subject and comments can be filled. 
Up on clicking submit button, the specfied email will recieve the details. Cant seem to locate the problem.

here is the html code of contact.html

```
 <form id="ajax-contact-form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="form-padding">
                    <label for="f1">Your name(required):</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="f1" class="form-text" value=""/>
                    <label for="f2">Insurance type:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="category" id="f2" class="form-text" value="" size="40"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="form-padding">
                    <label for="f3">Your email(required):</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="f3" class="form-text" value="" size="40"/>
                    <label for="f4">Subject:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="f4" class="form-text" value="" size="40"/>        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span8">
                <div class="form-padding">
                    <label for="f5">Message(required):</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="f5" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                    <!-- send mail configuration -->
                    <input type="hidden" value="myemail@gmail.com" name="to" id="to" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="myemail@gmail.com" name="from" id="from" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="From contact form" name="subject" id="subject" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="send-mail.php" name="sendMailUrl" id="sendMailUrl" />
                    <!-- ENDS send mail configuration -->               
                    <p><input type="button" class="button red small" value="Submit Form" name="submit" id="submit" /></p>
        </form>
```

AND MY SEND-MAIL.PHP

```
    <?php
        //vars
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $to = explode(',', $_POST['to'] );

        $from = $_POST['email'];

        //data
        $msg = "NAME: "  .$_POST['f1']    ."<br>\n";
        $msg .= "INSURANCE: "  .$_POST['f2']    ."<br>\n";
        $msg .= "EMAIL: "  .$_POST['f3']    ."<br>\n";
        $msg .= "SUBJECT: "  .$_POST['f4']    ."<br>\n";
        $msg .= "COMMENTS: "  .$_POST['f5']    ."<br>\n";

        //Headers
        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;


        //send for each mail
        foreach($to as $mail){
           mail($mail, $subject, $msg, $headers);
        }

        ?>
```

My JS function

```
// contact form
$("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() {
var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "send-mail.php",
    data: str,
    success: function(msg) {
        if(msg == 1) {
            result = '<div class="alert success fade in">Your message has been sent. Thank you!<a href="#" class="close-alert" data-dismiss="alert"></a></div>';
            $("#ajax-contact-form").hide();
        } else {result = msg;}
        $('#form-message').hide();
        $('#form-message').html(result);
        $('#form-message').fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
return false;
});
```

My Questions

1. There seems to be an error, cant send mails. Im a naive. Any help would be appreciated.
2. How to do i show a success message after clicking submit button.

Thanks

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: No error message, thats the worry, its not doing what it is supposed to, i.e send email out

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have to complete your form open tag

```
<form id="ajax-contact-form" method="POST" action="send-mail.php">
```

unless you using Ajax, you have to provide the ajax code in your question.